# What's the difference between Tomcat JNDI based and Spring/Hibernate DS based connection pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have been looking into connection pool options and it is somewhat unclear to me what the differences in Tomcat JNDI connection pool approach is, compared to the Spring/Hibernate solution to the same.

Whilst it's possible to achieve the pooling using either [1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html), [2](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html), the specific application we have would lend itself better to us using Tomcat given the constraints we have.

Reading about, there is some suggestion to [just stick with Spring/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376957/tomcat-jndi-connection-pool-docs-random-connection-closed-exceptions).

Are there any notable differences worth mentioning between each approach? What are other's personal experience of one or the other (or both) - I have successfully been using Spring/Hibernate for years now.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think, if you use JNDI connection pool, it will be container-wide (e.g. shared between several web applications). If you define a connection pool in your Spring context, it will leave within your context, (e.g. it will be application-wide). I haven't used Tomcat+JNDI option, so I cannot give really good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two approaches are complementary, not mutually exclusive. In production systems, the likes of Spring/Hibernate will obtain a reference to the connection pool from the appserver, in the form of a `javax.sql.DataSource`, usually by looking for it on the JNDI tree. It generally considered to be the appserver's "job" to manage the connection pool and its connections.

Remember, JNDI is just a place for registering objects for sharing, it does in itself mandate any given connection pool mechanism. The app server creates and configures the pool, and the applications (via Spring/Hibernate/whatever) use it.

It's just as valid, however, for the applications to configure and manage the connection pool themselves. This does mean a bit more work for the application, though, with less reliance on the appserver.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. Now supposing I went with Tomcat JNDI based Pooling I assume therefore I would need to turn the pooling config in Spring off, in order not to pool on top of Tomcat's JNDI pooling... ?

Comment: Spring doesn't have a connection pool implementation, it uses whatever `DataSource` object you give it - if that happens to be a connection pool supplied by Tomcat via JNDI, so much the better.

Comment: true, sorry I meant Hibernate

Comment: Oh right. Yes, Hibernate's connection pooling is strictly for development use, it's not intended for production systems - it says as much in the manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc